# .NET XDocument processing issue

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML and I'm trying to get the "MarcEntryInfo" element  value where its  is equal to 974, does anyone know how this is expressed using XDocument.

In my C# code I have tried to get the value but it can't seem to retrieve the value.

Another way to phrase what I'm asking is if the child tags of a MarcEntryInfo has a entryID of a certain value return the string value of the text child element of that particular MarcEntryInfo.

Thanks

```
<LookupTitleInfoResponse xmlns="http://schemas.sirsidynix.com/symws/standard">
  <TitleInfo>
    <titleID>4971729</titleID>
    <CallInfo>
      <libraryID>PRODUCT</libraryID>
      <classificationID>ALPHANUM</classificationID>
      <callNumber>WS6689</callNumber>
      <numberOfCopies>1</numberOfCopies>
      <ItemInfo>
        <itemID>4971729-1001</itemID>
        <itemTypeID>TAPE</itemTypeID>
        <currentLocationID>STORE</currentLocationID>
        <homeLocationID>STORE</homeLocationID>
        <chargeable>true</chargeable>
        <fixedTimeBooking>false</fixedTimeBooking>
      </ItemInfo>
    </CallInfo>
    <BibliographicInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>MD-ARK</label>
        <entryID>974</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>ark:/81055/vdc_100000006155.0x2afcee</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>L-ARK: INGESTED</label>
        <entryID>975</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>ark:/81055/vdc_100055625567.0x000002</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>SHELFMARK</label>
        <entryID>087</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>WS6689</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>VR</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Unpublished series</label>
        <entryID>441</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>Wildlife species reels</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>MTR</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Other ref. no.</label>
        <entryID>091</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>W Melanogrammus aeglefinus r1</text>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Product title</label>
        <entryID>499</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>Melanogrammus aeglefinus r1</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>MAR</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Format</label>
        <entryID>310</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>1 tape reel</text>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Cataloguing status</label>
        <entryID>971</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>prc</text>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Data source</label>
        <entryID>976</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>WSF</text>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
      <MarcEntryInfo>
        <label>Content  code</label>
        <entryID>312</entryID>
        <indicators></indicators>
        <text>a</text>
        <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
      </MarcEntryInfo>
    </BibliographicInfo>
  </TitleInfo>
</LookupTitleInfoResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I truncated the XML for the purpose of brevity. A few things to note:

- You need to declare the namespace in order to find your element
- You need to reference the elements by namespace in your XPath expression
- You should select the `entryID` element having your target value and navigate up to its parent

Example code is below. Once you have the `entryInfo` element you can extract any information from its child elements that you need.

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<LookupTitleInfoResponse xmlns=""http://schemas.sirsidynix.com/symws/standard"">
      <TitleInfo>
        <titleID>4971729</titleID>
        <CallInfo>
          <libraryID>PRODUCT</libraryID>
          <classificationID>ALPHANUM</classificationID>
          <callNumber>WS6689</callNumber>
          <numberOfCopies>1</numberOfCopies>
          <ItemInfo>
            <itemID>4971729-1001</itemID>
            <itemTypeID>TAPE</itemTypeID>
            <currentLocationID>STORE</currentLocationID>
            <homeLocationID>STORE</homeLocationID>
            <chargeable>true</chargeable>
            <fixedTimeBooking>false</fixedTimeBooking>
          </ItemInfo>
        </CallInfo>
        <BibliographicInfo>
          <MarcEntryInfo>
            <label>MD-ARK</label>
            <entryID>974</entryID>
            <indicators></indicators>
            <text>ark:/81055/vdc_100000006155.0x2afcee</text>
            <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
          </MarcEntryInfo>
          <MarcEntryInfo>
            <label>Content  code</label>
            <entryID>312</entryID>
            <indicators></indicators>
            <text>a</text>
            <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
          </MarcEntryInfo>
        </BibliographicInfo>
      </TitleInfo>
    </LookupTitleInfoResponse>";

    var nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
    nsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.sirsidynix.com/symws/standard");

    var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    var entryInfo = doc.XPathSelectElement("//ns:entryID[contains(text(), '974')]/..", nsManager);
    Console.WriteLine(entryInfo);

    // Output:
    // <MarcEntryInfo xmlns="http://schemas.sirsidynix.com/symws/standard">
    //   <label>MD-ARK</label>
    //   <entryID>974</entryID>
    //   <indicators></indicators>
    //   <text>ark:/81055/vdc_100000006155.0x2afcee</text>
    //   <entryTypeCodes>L</entryTypeCodes>
    // </MarcEntryInfo>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Linq to XML here

below code will let you get all entry Id tags on the XML

if you need a specific value you can add .SingleOrDefault(el=>el.Value=="974");

```html
var xml = XElement.Load(YourDocumentPath);

var allEntryIds = xml.Elements()
    .SingleOrDefault(el=>el.Name.LocalName=="TitleInfo")
    .Elements()
        .SingleOrDefault(el => el.Name.LocalName == "BibliographicInfo")
        .Elements()
            .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "MarcEntryInfo")
            .Elements()
                .Where(el => el.Name.LocalName == "entryID");
```